# XHR based ajax unable to upload files

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I've a pretty simple javascript function which tries to send formdata along with an attached file to a php script. Below is my html and javascript code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery AJAX Submit Form</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="button" onclick="upload()" value="Upload">
</form><span id="msg"></span>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function upload(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://localhost/2.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhttp.send(formData);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is my php script "2.php":

```
<?php  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $_POST['name'].$_FILES['file']['name']);
    fclose($myfile);
    echo 'file written';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "success";
?>
```

The above php script doesn't has any problem because it is able to retrieve the input text as **$_POST['name']** and save it in the text file created. Also the script is successfully able to retrieve the file submitted and save it, only when I submit the html form normally without any javascript.

I want to submit both the input field data and selected file via XHR api only and not through fetch api.

Comment: Have you console->network checked?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: browser (firefox) -> tools for developers->network->reply - request